# C# Выбор диапазона даты в monthCalendar пользователем

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!

Как реализовать возможность выбор диапазона даты пользователем в объекте monthCalendar или может-быть иные решения имеются. 
Проблема в том, что `SelectionRange` позволяет выбирать только одним кликом (растянуть до нужных дат) и в рамках одного месяца. 
А задача: открыть календарь. выбрать кликом дату *2002.05.05* а затем выбрать кликом *2016.05.05* и получить этот диапазон.

Спасибо!

Сразу оговорюсь: событие `DateChanged` имеется, а также имеется возможность выбрать диапазон путем драг&дропа перетаскивая курсор, в рамках одного месяца. Выбрать даты с разных месяцев можно, с использованием **Shift**. Но это юзер-френдли
Хочется именно, по описанному алгоритму выше. `Клик=startData + Клик=endData`

Comment: Добавьте код, чтобы вопрос стал более понятным.

Comment: Сделайте два календаря один под другим. Щёлкнули верхний, спрятали его на задний план. Для второго щелчка вылез другой. И так циклически их щёлкать. Где при этом стартдата, где енд как-нибудь разберётесь. Сам бы попробовал так сделать, да некогда.

Answer (score 1):

А что вам мешает сделать два поля `startData, endData` и, допустим, при присвоении значения endData по клику программно создавать `SelectionRange`?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?